# python select through loop from a list by value position

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm newbie in python self-learning, I'm trying to make a menu that select from a list, I managed to select from the list by the value, but what I actually need is to select by value position, like my first example "Mango", any solution with explanations is highly appreciated

```
# importing libraries
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # setting title
        self.setWindowTitle("Jox Store ")

        # setting geometry
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 600, 400)

        # calling method
        self.UiComponents()

        # showing all the widgets
        self.show()

    # method for widgets
    def UiComponents(self):

        # creating a combo box widget
        self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)

        # setting geometry of combo box
        self.combo_box.setGeometry(200, 150, 150, 40)

        # geek list
        jox_menu = ["Select From The Menu","Orange", "Mango", "Apple", "Strawberry"]
        
        # making it editable
        self.combo_box.setEditable(True)

        # adding list of items to combo box
        self.combo_box.addItems(jox_menu)

        # adding action to combo box
        self.combo_box.activated.connect(self.jox_menu)

        # creating label to
        self.label = QLabel(self) 

        # setting geometry of the label
        self.label.setGeometry(200, 230, 400, 40)

    # method called by combo box
    def jox_menu(self):
     self.combo_box.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onChange)

    def onChange(self, jox_menu):
     
     for x in jox_menu:
      if x == (jox_menu[2]):
        self.label.setText("Mango Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 100$")
      elif jox_menu == "Orange":
        self.label.setText("Orange Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 30$")
      elif jox_menu == "Apple":
        self.label.setText("Apple Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 10$")
      elif jox_menu == "Strawberry":
        self.label.setText("Strawberry Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 150$")
      else:
            self.label.clear()

# create pyqt5 app
App = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create the instance of our Window
window = Window()

# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I see one problem - you use the same name `jox_menu` for three elements - (1) list `jox_menu = [...]`, (2) function `def jox_menu(self)`, (3) argument `def onChange(self, jox_menu):` - and all this can make mess because you use `jox_menu[2]` probably to get item from list `jox_menu` but you get single char from argument `jox_menu`. You should use different names. And you have to use `self.` in `self.jox_menu = [...]` to have access to this list in other functions.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `self.combo_box.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onChange)`. You could directly assign `onChange` to `self.combo_box.currentTextChanged.connect(self.onChange)` or `self.combo_box.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onChange)`. First could get text as value, and second should get index as value - in `def onChange(self, value):`

Comment: I would rather keep data as dictionar `self.data = {"Mango": "Mango Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 100$", ...}` and then it is simpler to select text for label using text selected in  combobox - and it doesn't need `for`-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one problem: you use the same name `jox_menu` for three elements

1. list `jox_menu = [...]`,
2. function `def jox_menu(self)`,
3. argument in `def onChange(self, jox_menu):`

and all this can make mess because you use `jox_menu[2]` probably to get item from list `jox_menu` but it gets single char from argument `jox_menu`.

You should use different names.

And you have to use `self.` in `self.jox_menu = [...]` to have access to this list in other functions.

I also don't understand why you use

```
self.combo_box.activated.connect(self.jox_menu)
```

and

```
self.combo_box.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onChange)
```

You could directly assign `onChange` to

```
self.combo_box.currentTextChanged.connect(self.onChange)
```

or

```
self.combo_box.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onChange)
```

First sends text as value, and second send index as value in `def onChange(self, value):`

---

Minimal working code:

```
# importing libraries
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # setting title
        self.setWindowTitle("Jox Store ")

        # setting geometry
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 600, 400)

        # calling method
        self.UiComponents()

        # showing all the widgets
        self.show()

    # method for widgets
    def UiComponents(self):

        # creating a combo box widget
        self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)

        # setting geometry of combo box
        self.combo_box.setGeometry(200, 150, 150, 40)

        # geek list
        self.jox_menu = ["Select From The Menu","Orange", "Mango", "Apple", "Strawberry"]
        
        # making it editable
        self.combo_box.setEditable(True)

        # adding list of items to combo box
        self.combo_box.addItems(self.jox_menu)

        # adding action to combo box
        self.combo_box.currentTextChanged.connect(self.onChange)
        #self.combo_box.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onChange)

        # creating label to
        self.label = QLabel(self) 

        # setting geometry of the label
        self.label.setGeometry(200, 230, 400, 40)

    def onChange(self, value):
        print('onChange:', value)

        if value in self.jox_menu[2]:
            self.label.setText("Mango Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 100$")
        elif value == self.jox_menu[1]:
            self.label.setText("Orange Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 30$")
        elif value == self.jox_menu[3]:
            self.label.setText("Apple Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 10$")
        elif value == self.jox_menu[4]:
            self.label.setText("Strawberry Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 150$")
        else:
            self.label.clear()

# create pyqt5 app
App = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create the instance of our Window
window = Window()

# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

---

**EDIT:**

Frankly I could keep data as

```
self.data = {
    'Mango': "Mango Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 100$",
    'Orange': "Orange Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 30$",
    'Apple': "Apple Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 10$",
    'Strawberry': "Strawberry Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 150$",
}
```

and I would create menu using

```
self.jox_menu = ["Select From The Menu"] + list(self.data.keys())
```

and later it would need shorter code to change text

```
def onChange(self, value):
    print('onChange:', value)

    if value in self.data:
        text = self.data[value]
        self.label.setText(text)
    else:
        self.label.clear()
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
# importing libraries
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = {
            'Mango': "Mango Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 100$",
            'Orange': "Orange Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 30$",
            'Apple': "Apple Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 10$",
            'Strawberry': "Strawberry Is A Good Choice Your Bill is 150$",
        }
            
        # setting title
        self.setWindowTitle("Jox Store ")

        # setting geometry
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 600, 400)

        # calling method
        self.UiComponents()

        # showing all the widgets
        self.show()

    # method for widgets
    def UiComponents(self):

        # creating a combo box widget
        self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)

        # setting geometry of combo box
        self.combo_box.setGeometry(200, 150, 150, 40)

        # geek list
        self.jox_menu = ["Select From The Menu"] + list(self.data.keys())
        
        # making it editable
        self.combo_box.setEditable(True)

        # adding list of items to combo box
        self.combo_box.addItems(self.jox_menu)

        # adding action to combo box
        #self.combo_box.activated.connect(self.onActivated)
        
        self.combo_box.currentTextChanged.connect(self.onChange)
        #self.combo_box.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onChange)

        # creating label to
        self.label = QLabel(self) 

        # setting geometry of the label
        self.label.setGeometry(200, 230, 400, 40)

    # method called by combo box
    #def onActivated(self, idx):
    #    print('onActivated:', idx)

    def onChange(self, value):
        print('onChange:', value)

        if value in self.data:
            text = self.data[value]
            self.label.setText(text)
        else:
            self.label.clear()

# create pyqt5 app
App = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create the instance of our Window
window = Window()

# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())
```